# rails getting html from Rack::BodyProxy object in middleware

Tags: ruby-on-rails, middleware

I'm calling controllers from middleware like:

```
@status, @headers, @articles = ArticlesController.action('index').call(env)
```

And really, I just want the html from that @articles but the @articles is a huge big Rack::BodyProxy object and the html is buried deep in it.

The stranger thing is that I find it like:

```
articles_html = @articles.instance_variable_get(:@body).instance_variable_get(:@stream).instance_variable_get(:@buf)[0]
```

but another developer accesses it like this:

```
articles_html = @articles.instance_variable_get(:@response).instance_variable_get(:@stream).instance_variable_get(:@buf)[0]
```

So that makes for a pretty ugly ternary:

```
 articles_html = @articles.instance_variable_get(:@response).nil? ? @articles.instance_variable_get(:@body).instance_variable_get(:@stream).instance_variable_get(:@buf)[0] : @articles.instance_variable_get(:@response).instance_variable_get(:@stream).instance_variable_get(:@buf)[0]
```

Plus, I'm not sure if that's going to cover all the cases.

What's a better way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a very old question but in the off chance that anybody stumnles upon this...

Any method call to an instance of `Rack::BodyProxy` ultimately gets passed on to the resulting body array. That means you can simply call `first` to retrieve the body string, or call `each` to iterate through the array.

You can see the delegation [here](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/body_proxy.rb#L39-L42)

Answer (score 0):

Just thanks for the previous answer, you can also call `.join` if you want just have the full body string in a variable.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31932255)